# How to bind mousehover event to select option in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a list of sound, the requirement is relevant sound should play when the mouse hover on the sound name in the list.

```
  <select class="cc-select-dropdown form-control" id="defaultMerge"      formControlName="DefaultNotificationAlert">
        <option *ngFor="let option of soundList" (mouseover)='playSound()'   [ngValue]="option">{{option}}</option>
```

The problem is I couldn't find any event that works with the select options

Answer (score 1):

you can't catch events like that in `<option>` it's up to the browser. if you want you have to write a custom `dropdown` yourself

Answer (score 0):

you can't do it in the `<option>` of the `<select>` tag. But you can do it with `<mat-select>`, just use `(mouseover)` in `<mat-option>`.